# Null pointer exception log and Eventlog class code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Here are the list of my android codes including the java, xml

Java Code:

```
 package thesis.file;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.net.ParseException;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Eventlogs extends ListActivity {
 JSONArray jArray;
 String result = null;
 InputStream is = null;
 StringBuilder sb=null;
 int ct_id;
 String ct_name;

 ListView yourListView = getListView();

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.eventlogs);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

//http post

try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://amlan.aytee.info/event.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
  }

 //convert response to string
 try{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
 sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
 String line="0";
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
  }
  is.close();

  result=sb.toString();
  }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
  }

 //paring data

 try{
  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         ct_id=json_data.getInt("e_id");
         ct_name=json_data.getString("event");
         //ct_datetime=json_data.get
     }
  }catch(JSONException e1){
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No events found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
  }

}
 }
```

Android manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.file"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ThesisActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity android:name =".MenuClass" android:label ="@string/app_name"></activity>
     <activity android:name =".SalesReport" android:label ="@string/app_name"></activity>
     <activity android:name =".EventLogs" android:label ="@string/app_name"></activity>
     <activity android:name =".LanStatus" android:label ="@string/app_name"></activity>

</application>
```

eventlogs.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Logs"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"


    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem with my code?This is the log cat errors:

```
     12-21 01:30:19.014: W/dalvikvm(708): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)

     12-21 01:30:19.023: E/AndroidRuntime(708): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

     12-21 01:30:19.058: E/AndroidRuntime(708): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {thesis.file/thesis.file.Eventlogs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I was just confused about the list activity and activity

here is the code:

```
package thesis.file;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;  
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;  
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class ThesisActivity extends Activity  {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button btnLogin;
EditText txtUsername, txtPassword;
TextView txtError;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);  
    txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    txtError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtError);
    /*btnLogin.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);*/
    //Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);  


/*@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    n
    super.onDestroy();
}*/

 btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtUsername.getText().toString()));  
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", txtPassword.getText().toString()));   


    //String valid = "1";  
    String response = null;  
    try {  
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://amlan.aytee.info/user.php", postParameters);  //Enter Your remote PHP,ASP, Servlet file link  
    String res=response.toString();  
    // res = res.trim();  
    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");  
    //error.setText(res);  
    if(res.contains("1")){
    txtError.setText("correct username");
        //txtError.setText(res);    
    Intent i = new Intent(ThesisActivity.this, MenuClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
    txtError.setText("incorrect username");  
    } 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    txtUsername.setText(e.toString());  

    }

}
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: By "creating a new question" we do not mean "completely copy the content from your old question and paste it in a new one". 

What is your new problem, and what have you done so far?

Comment: Where are you exactly calling EvenLogs?

Comment: Remove this whole thing, post null pointer exception log and Eventlog class  code..

Comment: Can we also see how you call your intent?

Comment: if (v.getId() == R.id.btnEventLogs)
  {
   
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Eventlogs.class));
   
  } here it is Sir @Dante

Answer (score 0):

your package is wrong.

in the manifest :

```
package="my.file"
```

in the classes :

```
package thesis.file;
```